# How to compute the derivative of a product of matrices and vectors with respect to the vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Suppose $A$ is a $j\times k$ matrix and $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$. How would I compute the derivative of $Axx^{\top}A^{\top}$ with respect to $x$?

Please provide as much justification as possible, as I am trying to teach myself derivatives in higher dimension.

Thank you.

Comment: it is a $j\times j\times k$ tensor... Are you sure it is what you want?

Comment: $xx^T$ is not a real number though... It is a $k\times k$ matrix...

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken then. I was trying to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}_{i}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}||\boldsymbol{y}_{i}-\boldsymbol{\beta}-A\boldsymbol{x}_{i}||^{2}$. I thought the last term of the sum would be $Ax_ix_i^{\top}A^{\top}$ after taking inner product with itself to compute the square of the norm.

Comment: Now that I look again, I also had the simplification that $A$ is orthonormal. Not sure if this provides a useful complexity reduction.

Comment: Perhaps given orthonormality we may have $A\boldsymbol{x}_{i}\cdot A\boldsymbol{x}_{i}=||A\boldsymbol{x}_{i}||^{2}=||\boldsymbol{x}_{i}||^{2}$?

Comment: You changed the order. In general if $v$ is a vector, then
$\|v\|^2  = v^Tv$ not $vv^T$. And yes, $\|Ax\|^2 = \|x\|^2$ if $A$ is orthogonal